# what is difference between Integer+1,integer++ in the static map initialize block

Tags: java

In my code I have as initialized the map as mentioned below,

```
Static Map<intger,String> map =new Hashmap<intger,String>();
Static 
{
Integer count=0;
 map.put(count+1,"ranjith");
 map.put(count+1,"kumar");
}
```

Result: 1,kumar so last value only getting added into the static map

```
But if try like below

map.put(count++,"ranjith");
map.put(count++,"edr");

Result :i
1,ranjith
2,edr
```

So now it is coming as I give..

So What is difference between count+1,
    count++
  Can anybody help me to understand the difference between Integer+1 and Integer++ inside static initialize?

Comment: What does count+1 do? What does count++ do?

Answer (score 1):

`count + 1` : Supplies a value that is 1 greater than `count`.

`count++`: Has the same effect as above, but in addition, the `count` variable itself will be set to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

`count+1` is an expression, resulting in a value, but not changing count. `count++` also changes count itself.

Answer (score 0):

beautiful

The unary operator `++` called as Increment operator increments a value by 1;

`count++` is the same as `count += 1` and this can be expressed as `count = count + 1`

`count + 1` do not modify the `count` value but only create one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer count=0;
map.put(count+1,"ranjith");
map.put(count+1,"kumar");
```

Is equivalent to

```
map.put(1,"ranjith");
map.put(1,"kumar");
```

While

```
map.put(count++,"ranjith");
map.put(count++,"edr");
```

Is equivalent to

```
map.put(1,"ranjith");
map.put(2,"edr");
```

(assuming that count was initialized to 1).